# Insert statements working when inserting emojis, but throws error when using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Running the query,

`INSERT INTO table (ref_id, user_id, role_id, text)
VALUES (233, 3, 40, 'Hdhdhdhhzhzhzzhjzj 我爱你 ❌')`

works just fine in Sequel Pro, but when using eloquent, it throws an error,

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x9C\xF0\x9F...' for column 'text' at row 1 (SQL: INSERT INTO table (ref_id, user_id, role_id, text) VALUES (233, 3, 40, 'Hdhdhdhhzhzhzzhjzj 我爱你 ❌')"
```

Comment: Maybe the driver has the wrong character set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Cause of the problem:

Laravel, by default, uses `utf8` as charset for MySQL. In MySQL, a UTF8 char is up to 3 bytes long (`utf8` is an alias for `utf8mb3`). Whereas Emoji characters are up to 4 bytes long.

Therefore we need to use `utf8mb4` as our charset.

#### Solution:

**1. Open your `config/database.php`**

**2. Find the MySQL section:**

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    [...]
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    [....]
```

**3. Change charset, collation to `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` respectively:**

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    [...]
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    [....]
```

**4. Save and reset your database:**

Note that if you reset your database, all of your data will be erased!

> php artisan migrate:reset